# How to specify a path relative to user home directory for destination when using rsync over ssh

Tags: rsync

I am using rsync over ssh and trying without success to sync files to a place inside user home directory.

All the time rsync seams to want to use full paths.

Tried things like:

- `rsync --rsh=ssh /src/  user@server:/dst` - obviously creates it in root if it can
- `rsync --rsh=ssh  /src/  user@server:~/dst`
- `rsync --rsh=ssh  /src/  user@server:~dst` - creades `~dst` in root!

Comment: What is the result of 2nd command? It should copy the contents of directory `/src` into the `dst` directory under user home directory.

Comment: @Khaled it doesnt because it gets expanded by the local shell to the home directory of the current user, not the home directory of the remote user.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Dont try to use an absolute file path on the destination, the default is home.

Leave the path off to place it in home:

```
rsync /src user@server:
```

Or use a relative path to place it somewhere relative to home

```
rsync /src user@server:srccopy
```

Note you dont need `--rsh=ssh` either as its the default.

**EDIT**:
If you wish to copy into the home directory of a user that isnt the one youre logging into the remote machine with, you need to escape the `~` with quotes or a backslash. For example

```
rsync /src user@server:\~otheruser/
```